# Format data nicely

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am given data from an API in a format that is pretty difficult to use (in the mannor that is necessary to be used in) - I do not have the ability to modify the API. Below is an example of the data I am given:

```
    $data = array(
        array('day' => 'Monday', 'start' => 1100, 'end' => 1300),
        array('day' => 'Tuesday', 'start' => 1100, 'end' => 1300),
        array('day' => 'Wednesday', 'start' => 1100, 'end' => 1300),
        array('day' => 'Thursday', 'start' => 1200, 'end' => 1300),
        array('day' => 'Friday', 'start' => 1200, 'end' => 1300),
        array('day' => 'Saturday', 'start' => 1200, 'end' => 1300),
        array('day' => 'Sunday', 'start' => 1200, 'end' => 1400)
    );
```

The data may not include all seven days of the week, start and end vary between 0000 and 2400. I am trying to come up with a way to format the data with the following output: `Monday - Wednesday (1100-1300), Thursday - Saturday (1200-1300), Sunday (1200-1400)` basically, contiguous days (whose start and end times are the same) are separated by a hypen.

I am kind of trying to avoid a huge block of ugly code

Comment: It shouldn't be that ugly at all, just loop through the days of the week and compare start and end times.  The only slightly tricky part would be to make sure that you're covering days in the right order, but that can be hard coded (`$days_of_week=array("Monday","Tuesday",...,"Sunday");`).

Comment: Is there guaranteed to only be a single sub-array for each day of the week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugliness is in the eye of the beholder. ;) I think this is OK, but of course it might be exactly what you're trying to avoid.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array('day' => 'Monday', 'start' => 1100, 'end' => 1300),
    array('day' => 'Tuesday', 'start' => 1100, 'end' => 1300),
    array('day' => 'Wednesday', 'start' => 1100, 'end' => 1300),
    array('day' => 'Thursday', 'start' => 1200, 'end' => 1300),
    array('day' => 'Friday', 'start' => 1200, 'end' => 1300),
    array('day' => 'Saturday', 'start' => 1200, 'end' => 1300),
    array('day' => 'Sunday', 'start' => 1200, 'end' => 1400)
);

$periods = array();

$start = $end = $i = -1;

foreach ($data as $datum) {
    if ($start != $datum['start'] || $end != $datum['end']) {
        $i++;
        $start = $datum['start'];
        $end   = $datum['end'];

        $periods[$i] = array(
                          'start'    => $start, 
                          'end'      => $end,
                          'startDay' => $datum['day']);
    }
    $periods[$i]['endDay'] = $datum['day'];
}

foreach ($periods as $k => $period) {
    echo ($k) ? ', ' : '';
    if ($period['startDay'] === $period['endDay']) {
        echo $period['startDay'];
    } else {
        echo "{$period['startDay']} - {$period['endDay']}";
    }
    echo " ({$period['start']} - {$period['end']})";
}
```

Would output:

```
Monday - Wednesday (1100 - 1300), Thursday - Saturday (1200 - 1300), Sunday (1200 - 1400)
```

Comment: Obviously, my solution assumes the data is encountered in the correct order in the first place. Also, if you're concerned about making your code look messy, place that in a function library or class elsewhere, and call `Utilities::formatDatesNicely($data)`. =)

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
function data_to_array(&$data, $cols) {
  foreach($data as &$value) {
    $value = array_combine($cols, explode(',', $value));
  }
}

$data = Array(
  'Monday,1200,1400',
  'Monday,1200,1400',
  'Monday,1200,1400',
  'Monday,1200,1400',
  'Monday,1200,1400',
  'Monday,1200,1400',
  'Monday,1200,1400',
  'Monday,1200,1400',
  'Monday,1200,1400',
  'Monday,1200,1400',
  'Monday,1200,1400'
);

data_to_array($data, Array('day','start','end'));
// now $data is again ugly block of data :)
```

now you can keep it in text file 
**data.txt:**

```
Monday,1200,1400
Monday,1200,1400
Monday,1200,1400
Monday,1200,1400
Monday,1200,1400
Monday,1200,1400
Monday,1200,1400
Monday,1200,1400
Monday,1200,1400
Monday,1200,1400
Monday,1200,1400
```

**your php file:**

```
$data = explode("\n", file_get_contents('data.txt'));
data_to_array($data, Array('day','start','end'));
// now $data is again ugly block of data :)
```